# Apache memory leak with Subversion server

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, mod-dav-svn

Does anyone know of a way to fix the Apache memory leak in relation to Subversion Server? We have a windows server 2003 machine running Apache to host Subversion. From day one, we have had memory leak issues and have not found a solution yet. All we do is monitor our server when when the memory use reaches near the max it can handle we have to restart Apache.

Comment: It could be interesting to add the versions of Apache and svn you are using (possibly also how you detect the memory leak or any relevant information).

Answer (score 5):

We had a similar issue with SVN 1.6.6, Win 2K3 32-bit, CollabNet install.
We tried using [this](http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2009-10/0823.shtml) info from the SVN mailing list related to MaxMemFree and it seems to have worked for us so far.

> Try adding the MaxMemFree Apache directive to your httpd.conf file. This 
>   seems to force apache to "clean up" memory more often. I use:
>
> ```
> MaxMemFree 512
> ```
>
> That, along with not using mod_deflate, and changing some SSL 
>   parameters (SSLSessionCache and SSLMutex) seems to have stabilized 
>   our apache memory usage on Windows.

Comment: same issue with 1.6.2, thanks for possible solution - i'll try that

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug raised against it here: http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3084

Unfortuantly, there's no fix yet. But it may be worth trying some of the workarounds listed on there until there is a proper fix. It's also worth following some of the links in the comments that go to a number of threads that discuss the issue as various workarounds are listed within those threads as well as those amongst the bug comments.

Answer (score 0):

We have same issue after upgrading Apache 2.2.9 and SVN 1.5.5 to Apache 2.2.14 and SVN 1.6.6. It look like that it is SVN 1.6.x related issue, because we didnt have this problem anything before until upgrade..

I hope that somebody have resolution for it...